# How to do multiple validations based on one http call in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, asynchronous, custom-validators

I have a field on a form with lots of validation.

At first, I had it structured into multiple directives, each with its own error message.

However, the validation uses a back-end asynchronous call, so suddenly for one field I was making 5 http calls for the same dataservice. I am trying to figure out how to write this more efficiently.

I was wondering if it is possible to have one `$async` validator that calls the dataservice, and multiple regular `$validators` inside of the first asynchronous function after `.then`. I experimented with this but it doesn't seem to reach the nested `$validators` at all.

I also tried to do the call once in a service, but I don't know how to get it to update when the modelValue on the field changes, and consequently pass the information to the respective validation directives. Could I do this as async validation in a service and attach the response to scope for the directives to look for?

TLDR;

How can I make ONE http call and based off of the returned data, perform multiple validation checks, each with its own error?

FOR EXAMPLE

I have about four directives that all look like this:

```
angular.module('validationForField').directive('po', ['$q', '$sce', '$timeout', 'myService', function ($q, $sce, $timeout, myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, ngModel) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.validateField = function (modelValue) {
                var def = $q.defer();
                myService.httpcall(modelValue)
                    .then(function (response, modelValue) {
                        if (response.data.status === "Error") {  
                            return def.reject();
                        }
                     def.resolve();

                    }).catch(function(){
                    def.reject();
                });
                return def.promise;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Each one has different analysis of the data to return different error messages. Each one makes a call to myService.httpcall which ends up being redundant because they are all getting the same data.

I am trying to do

```
angular.module('validationForField').directive('po', ['$q', '$sce', '$timeout', 'myService', function ($q, $sce, $timeout, myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, ngModel) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.validateField = function (modelValue) {
                var def = $q.defer();
                myService.httpcall(modelValue)
                    .then(function (response, modelValue) {
                        if (response.data.status === "Error") {  
                            return def.reject();
                        }
                        ctrl.$validators.checkStatus = function (response) {
                             if (response.data.data.status === "10"){
                             return false
                         }
                        ctrl.$validators.checkPermissions = function (response) {
                             return response.data.data.permission){

                         }

                     def.resolve();

                    }).catch(function(){
                    def.reject();
                });
                return def.promise;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

This way there is the main async validator as to whether the http call is successful or not, and internal $validators that use that data when it returns

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or bin or at least share part of your code that related to your question!?

Comment: @mamos98 does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the backend service accepts a value (the value of the field to be validated) and returns a single response for all validations, e.g.:

```
// true would mean valid, string would mean invalid with the given error:
{
    businessRuleOne: true,
    businessRuleTwo: "The format is incorrect",
    ...
}
```

I believe the solution is executing the HTTP call in a service that caches the promise; the async validators call the service and retrieve the same promise, which they return. Some sample code with inline explanation:

```
// the service:
app.service('myService', function($http, $q) {
    // cache the requests, keyed by the model value
    var requestMap = {};

    this.httpcall = function(modelValue) {
        // if cached, return that (and do not make extra call)
        if( requestMap[modelValue] ) {
            return requestMap[modelValue];
        }
        // if not cahced, make the call...
        var promise = $http.get('....');
        // ...cache it...
        requestMap[modelValue] = promise;
        // ...and remember to remove it from cache when done
        promise.finally(function() {
            delete requestMap[modelValue];
        });
        return promise;
    };
});
```

Now the async validators can be implemented exactly as you post. Calling `myService.httpcall(modelValue)` will invoke the remote service only for the first call, the rest will reuse the cached promise.

---

Two more points: (1) This technique is called memoization. It is implemented by many libraries, e.g. [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.memoize), you may be able to use those to keep `myservice.httpcall()` clean. (2) You do not need an extra promise from the async validators, e.g.:

```
angular.module('validationForField').directive('po', ['$q', '$sce', '$timeout', 'myService', function ($q, $sce, $timeout, myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, ngModel) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.validateField = function (modelValue) {
                return myService.httpcall(modelValue)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.status === "Error") {  
                            return $q.reject();
                        }
                        return response;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I really like this solution. I tried implementing something similar, the problem I ran in to is that each directive was calling the service at the same time, so they all got to the if ( requestMap[modelValue] ) part, all got false, and then all proceeded to the $http.get. Perhaps my implementation for the if statement was incorrect. I will try to use your version and open a new question if that does not work.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, you must try hard for all calls to reach the "if" line simultaneously.